# Laravel Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. Still object when using toArray();

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have a table that I want to export via excel. I use the method `toArray();` and still I get the result as object. Here is my sample code

```
    $items = \DB::table('users')
            ->join('finances', 'users.id','=','finances.user_id')
            ->join('schoolyears', 'users.school_id','=','schoolyears.school_id')
            ->select('users.name','users.phone','users.section_id', 'users.student_school_id','finances.amount','finances.description','schoolyears.name as syear','finances.date')
            ->where('finances.date', '=' ,(\DB::raw("(select max(`date`) from finances f where finances.user_id=f.user_id)")))
            ->where('users.role','=','4' )
            ->where('users.school_id','=', $sid)
            ->get()->toArray();


        //    dd($items);


        } else {

            return redirect('home')->with('error', 'Invalid access');

        }

        \Excel::create($this->page_title . 's', function ($excel) use ($items) {
            $excel->sheet($this->page_title . 's', function ($sheet) use ($items) {
                $sheet->fromArray($items);
            });
```

The result I get when i `dd($items)`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#558 ▼
    +"name": "Annamarie Morar"
    +"phone": "(0997) 212-7919"
    +"section_id": null
    +"student_school_id": "50"
    +"amount": "500"
    +"description": "New Pays"
    +"syear": "SY-2019-2020"
    +"date": "2019-11-14"
  }
  1 => {#561 ▶}
]
```

What i want is like this so that i can export it as an excel file

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => array:10 [▼
    "FirstName" => "Madelynn"
    "LastName" => "Stokes"
    "Gender" => "female"
    "Birthday" => "2013-10-09"
    "Address" => "78A/40 Goodwin Meadow, Poblacion, Iloilo City 1333 Nueva Ecija"
    "PhoneNo" => "+63 (971) 659-8143"
    "Parent" => "Deondre Stokes"
    "SchoolID" => "521"
    "RFID" => "173"
    "Section" => null
  ]
  1 => array:10 [▶]
  2 => array:10 [▶]
  3 => array:10 [▶]
  4 => array:10 [▶]
  5 => array:10 [▶]
  6 => array:10 [▶]
  7 => array:10 [▶]
  8 => array:10 [▶]
]
```

Comment: you can try this `$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);`

Comment: try var_dump intead of dd what result you get? If it only feature dd. Also collect($items)->toArray() should work

Comment: Thanks @DhavalPurohit . Can you post your answer so that I can mark it as correct? And please explain your answer to me and why the result cant be converted to array when i use `toArray();`. THANKS

Comment: @daremachine Alreay answered by dhaval . Please explain to me what is wrong with my code

Comment: json decode/encode is workaround IMO

Comment: what do you mean by that sir @daremachine

Comment: I mean convert array collection to string and vice versa is ugly and might be memory expensive. Best native solution is @lagbox

Comment: ohh okay sir. I should try it maybe.

Comment: @daremachine Yes #lagbox solution is best solution. What i have given is just a quick fix.

Comment: laravel `toArray()` working fine with the eloquent model but not with `DB` facade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert each object to an array by transforming the Collection then turning the Collection into an array if you had to:

```
$items = DB::table(...)->.....->get()->transform(function ($item) {
    return (array) $item;
})->toArray();
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Collections - Methods - `transform`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-transform)

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. I will try it.